# Invoking RESTful webservices

Tags: java, web-services, rest

When we try to invoke RESTful webservices using Client code, does the consumer always have to physically mention the URL in real development and production world?

```
public class JaxRSClient {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        //Creating Client
        Client client=ClientBuilder.newClient();

        //Setting the target on client  
        WebTarget wtarget=client.target("http://localhost:8080/jersey/RestWebService/HelloREST/service");

        //Getting response          
        System.out.println(wtarget.request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really a matter of opinion and preference. As such it is not suitable for an SO question.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to keep the URL in a **config** file which contains configuration parameters of your application. Inject that into your client file and call the API.

**Advantages**:

1. Easy to change and maintain urls.
2. You do not have to rebuild you application every time you change the url.
3. Hide sensitive information e.g application secret keys.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a global properties file, where you'll keep all your configurable application constants and make sure there is a logic available to get updated global properties to your application.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer